# Disable dropdown option

Tags: jquery

I am creating dropdown options like so:

```
timeDropdown.append($("<option />").val(y).text(y));
```

How can I make this option `disabled` or not selectable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that https://jsfiddle.net/j0deghoo/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".sel").append($("<option />").attr('disabled', 'true').val('5').text('5'));
});
```

Comment: jQuery [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) should be used for properties instead of `.attr()` in jQuery v1.6+.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a disabled attribute on the `option`

```
timeDropdown.append($("<option />").attr('disabled', 'disabled').val(y).text(y));
```

Here an example https://jsfiddle.net/o80xed2w/1/

Comment: jQuery [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) should be used for properties instead of `.attr()` in jQuery v1.6+.

Answer (score 0):

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/d9b24hw1/

```
<select id="timeDropdown">
    <option>Select One</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#timeDropdown").append(
    $("<option disabled='disabled'></option>").val('y').text('y')
);
$("#timeDropdown").append(
    $("<option></option>").val('n').text('n')
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the disabled attribute. Simple and easy. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp